# Cannot deserialize instance of Class out of START_ARRAY token

Tags: java, java-11, jackson-databind

I am trying to read the below data into a java object, but it is somehow failing.

Expected input data to my method getInternalNodeMetadata:

**Event [status=PUBLISHED, header=EventHeader{bu_id='2', mart_id='null', eventProducer=DCSQUARE, eventType='CARRIER', eventTimestamp=Wed Oct 28 13:54:02 IST 2020, callbackEnpoint='http://test.com/test-app/services/carriers/3000', eventFulfiller=DCSQUARE, modeOfOperation=INSERT, additionalData='null', comments='null', tenants='[TenantInfo {bu_id=2, mart_id=2}]'}, payload=null]**

```
public Flux<Event> getInternalNodeMetadata(Flux<Message<String>> message) {
    System.out.println(message.toString());
    return message.flatMap(it -> {
        System.out.println("Payload: " + it.getPayload());
        String eventMessage = it.getPayload().substring(5,it.getPayload().length());
        System.out.println("eventMessage: " + eventMessage);
        Event event = null;
        try {
            event = objectMapper.readValue(eventMessage, Event.class);
        } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        List<Event> internalNodeMetadataList = new ArrayList<>();
        internalNodeMetadataList.add(event);
        return Flux.fromIterable(internalNodeMetadataList);
    });
}
```

The above code is failing at the line
**event = objectMapper.readValue(eventMessage, Event.class);**

I have used jackson-databind: 2.11.4 jar ( for reading the value from object mapper class com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper )

Error stacktrace:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException: Cannot deserialize instance of `com.test.events.Event` out of START_ARRAY token
 at [Source: (String)" [status=PUBLISHED, header=EventHeader{bu_id='2', mart_id='null', eventProducer=DCSQUARE, eventType='CARRIER', eventTimestamp=Wed Oct 28 13:54:02 IST 2020, callbackEnpoint='http://test.com/test-app/services/carriers/3000', eventFulfiller=DCSQUARE, modeOfOperation=INSERT, additionalData='null', comments='null', tenants='[TenantInfo {bu_id=2, mart_id=2}]'}, payload=null]"; line: 1, column: 2]
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.MismatchedInputException.from(MismatchedInputException.java:59)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.reportInputMismatch(DeserializationContext.java:1468)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1242)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.DeserializationContext.handleUnexpectedToken(DeserializationContext.java:1190)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeFromArray(BeanDeserializer.java:604)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer._deserializeOther(BeanDeserializer.java:190)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.deser.BeanDeserializer.deserialize(BeanDeserializer.java:166)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper._readMapAndClose(ObjectMapper.java:4526)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3468)
    at com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(ObjectMapper.java:3436)
    at com.test.node.metadata.core.NodeMetadataServiceFacade.lambda$getInternalNodeMetadata$0(NodeMetadataServiceFacade.java:47)
```

Can some please help me out of this. Thanks in advance!

Here is my Event class

```
package com.test.events;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "Event",
    propOrder = {"status", "header", "payload"}
)
@XmlRootElement(
    name = "Event"
)
public class Event<T> implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(
        name = "status",
        required = true
    )
    private Status status;
    @XmlElement(
        name = "header",
        required = true
    )
    private EventHeader header;
    private T payload;

    public Event() {
        this.status = Status.FAIL;
    }

    public Event(EventHeader header, T payload) {
        this.status = Status.FAIL;
        this.header = header;
        this.payload = payload;
    }

    public EventHeader getHeader() {
        if (this.header == null) {
            this.header = new EventHeader();
        }

        return this.header;
    }

    public EventHeader setHeader(EventHeader header) {
        this.header = header;
        return this.header;
    }

    public T getPayload() {
        return this.payload;
    }

    public Event setPayload(T payload) {
        this.payload = payload;
        return this;
    }

    public Status getStatus() {
        return this.status;
    }

    public Event setStatus(Status status) {
        this.status = status;
        return this;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "Event [status=" + this.status + ", header=" + this.header + ", payload=" + this.payload + "]";
    }
}
```

Here is my EventData class

```
package com.test.events;

import com.test.com.util.DateTypeAdapter;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlJavaTypeAdapter;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(
    name = "EventHeader"
)
@XmlRootElement(
    name = "EventHeader"
)
public class EventHeader implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    @XmlElement(
        name = "WM_BU.ID",
        required = true
    )
    private String bu_id;
    @XmlElement(
        name = "WM_MART.ID",
        required = false
    )
    private String mart_id;
    @XmlElement(
        name = "EventProducer",
        required = true
    )
    private EventHeader.CPSystem eventProducer;
    @XmlElement(
        name = "EventType",
        required = true
    )
    private String eventType;
    @XmlElement(
        name = "EventTimestamp",
        required = true
    )
    @XmlJavaTypeAdapter(DateTypeAdapter.class)
    private Date eventTimestamp;
    @XmlElement(
        name = "CallbackEnpoint",
        required = false
    )
    private String callbackEnpoint;
    @XmlElement(
        name = "EventFulfiller",
        required = true
    )
    private EventHeader.CPSystem eventFulfiller;
    @XmlElement(
        name = "ModeOfOperation",
        required = true
    )
    private EventHeader.ModeOfOperation modeOfOperation;
    @XmlElement(
        name = "AdditionalData",
        required = false
    )
    private String additionalData;
    @XmlElement(
        name = "Comments",
        required = false
    )
    private String comments;
    @XmlElement(
        name = "Tenants",
        required = false
    )
    private List<TenantInfo> tenants;

    public EventHeader() {
    }

    public EventHeader(String bu_id, String mart_id, EventHeader.CPSystem eventProducer, String eventType, Date eventTimestamp, String callbackEnpoint, EventHeader.CPSystem eventFulfiller, EventHeader.ModeOfOperation modeOfOperation, String additionalData, String comments) {
        this.bu_id = bu_id;
        this.mart_id = mart_id;
        this.eventProducer = eventProducer;
        this.eventType = eventType;
        this.eventTimestamp = eventTimestamp;
        this.callbackEnpoint = callbackEnpoint;
        this.eventFulfiller = eventFulfiller;
        this.modeOfOperation = modeOfOperation;
        this.additionalData = additionalData;
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public EventHeader(String bu_id, String mart_id, EventHeader.CPSystem eventProducer, String eventType, Date eventTimestamp, String callbackEnpoint, EventHeader.CPSystem eventFulfiller, EventHeader.ModeOfOperation modeOfOperation, String additionalData, String comments, List<TenantInfo> tenants) {
        this.bu_id = bu_id;
        this.mart_id = mart_id;
        this.eventProducer = eventProducer;
        this.eventType = eventType;
        this.eventTimestamp = eventTimestamp;
        this.callbackEnpoint = callbackEnpoint;
        this.eventFulfiller = eventFulfiller;
        this.modeOfOperation = modeOfOperation;
        this.additionalData = additionalData;
        this.comments = comments;
        this.tenants = tenants;
    }

    public String getBu_id() {
        return this.bu_id;
    }

    public void setBu_id(String bu_id) {
        this.bu_id = bu_id;
    }

    public String getMart_id() {
        return this.mart_id;
    }

    public void setMart_id(String mart_id) {
        this.mart_id = mart_id;
    }

    public EventHeader.CPSystem getEventProducer() {
        return this.eventProducer;
    }

    public void setEventProducer(EventHeader.CPSystem eventProducer) {
        this.eventProducer = eventProducer;
    }

    public String getEventType() {
        return this.eventType;
    }

    public void setEventType(String eventType) {
        this.eventType = eventType;
    }

    public Date getEventTimestamp() {
        return this.eventTimestamp;
    }

    public void setEventTimestamp(Date eventTimestamp) {
        this.eventTimestamp = eventTimestamp;
    }

    public String getCallbackEnpoint() {
        return this.callbackEnpoint;
    }

    public void setCallbackEnpoint(String callbackEnpoint) {
        this.callbackEnpoint = callbackEnpoint;
    }

    public EventHeader.CPSystem getEventFulfiller() {
        return this.eventFulfiller;
    }

    public void setEventFulfiller(EventHeader.CPSystem eventFulfiller) {
        this.eventFulfiller = eventFulfiller;
    }

    public EventHeader.ModeOfOperation getModeOfOperation() {
        return this.modeOfOperation;
    }

    public void setModeOfOperation(EventHeader.ModeOfOperation modeOfOperation) {
        this.modeOfOperation = modeOfOperation;
    }

    public String getAdditionalData() {
        return this.additionalData;
    }

    public void setAdditionalData(String additionalData) {
        this.additionalData = additionalData;
    }

    public String getComments() {
        return this.comments;
    }

    public void setComments(String comments) {
        this.comments = comments;
    }

    public List<TenantInfo> getTenants() {
        return this.tenants;
    }

    public void setTenants(List<TenantInfo> tenants) {
        this.tenants = tenants;
    }

    public String toString() {
        return "EventHeader{bu_id='" + this.bu_id + '\'' + ", mart_id='" + this.mart_id + '\'' + ", eventProducer=" + this.eventProducer + ", eventType='" + this.eventType + '\'' + ", eventTimestamp=" + this.eventTimestamp + ", callbackEnpoint='" + this.callbackEnpoint + '\'' + ", eventFulfiller=" + this.eventFulfiller + ", modeOfOperation=" + this.modeOfOperation + ", additionalData='" + this.additionalData + '\'' + ", comments='" + this.comments + '\'' + ", tenants='" + this.tenants + '\'' + '}';
    }

    public static enum CPSystem {
        DCSQUARE,
        IMS,
        OMS,
        FOCI,
        MCSE,
        LMS,
        LMDE,
        SIMS,
        GSCOPE,
        PARTNER_MASTER,
        PARTNER_PORTAL,
        CAP,
        SYNAPSE,
        LIMO;

        private CPSystem() {
        }
    }

    public static enum ModeOfOperation {
        INSERT,
        UPDATE,
        DELETE,
        PUT,
        POST;

        private ModeOfOperation() {
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my DataTypeAdapter class

```
package com.test.common.util;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.DatatypeConverter;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.adapters.XmlAdapter;
import javax.xml.datatype.DatatypeConfigurationException;

public class DateTypeAdapter extends XmlAdapter<String, Date> {
    public static final String DATE_TIME_FORMAT_REGEX = "[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]{1}|1[0-2]{1})-([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])T([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(([.]([0-9]{3}))?+)[-+][0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}";

    public DateTypeAdapter() {
    }

    public Date unmarshal(String v) throws ParseException {
        if (v != null && v.trim().length() > 0) {
            try {
                if (!v.matches("[0-9]{4}-(0[1-9]{1}|1[0-2]{1})-([0-2][0-9]|3[0-1])T([0-1][0-9]|2[0-3]):([0-5][0-9]):([0-5][0-9])(([.]([0-9]{3}))?+)[-+][0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}")) {
                    throw new ParseException("Invalid date format provided. Allowed date format should follow the format {yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.millisecs-+Zone}. e.g. 2015-11-30T16:12:05.195-08:00", 0);
                } else {
                    Calendar cal = DatatypeConverter.parseDateTime(v);
                    cal.setLenient(false);
                    return cal.getTime();
                }
            } catch (IllegalArgumentException var3) {
                throw new ParseException("Invalid date format " + v, 0);
            }
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public String marshal(Date v) throws ParseException, DatatypeConfigurationException {
        Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        c.setTime(v);
        String dateTime = DatatypeConverter.printDateTime(c).replace("Z", "+00:00");
        return dateTime;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are sending an array of Events to "getInternalNodeMetadata" and trying to deserialize it to single Event, that is why you are getting the error , you need it to deserialize it to a list of events

```
 event = objectMapper.readValue(eventMessage, Event.class);
```

Here you probably need to do something like

```
List<Event> eventList = mapper.readValue(eventMessage, List.class);
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I tried with using List even then it is not working. its throwing a different error now.  com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Unrecognized token 'status': was expecting (JSON String, Number, Array, Object or token 'null', 'true' or 'false')

Comment: @VijaySai can you post the output of the print statements?
  System.out.println("Payload: " + it.getPayload());
        String eventMessage = it.getPayload().substring(5,it.getPayload().length());
        System.out.println("eventMessage: " + eventMessage);

Comment: Output is already shown in the stacktrace, it is just that the initial string "Event " is removed from the input string and it will be like "[status=PUBLISHED, header=EventHeader{bu_id='2', mart_id='null', eventProducer=DCSQUARE, eventType='CARRIER', eventTimestamp=Wed Oct 28 13:54:02 IST 2020, callbackEnpoint='http://test.com/test-app/services/carriers/3000', eventFulfiller=DCSQUARE, modeOfOperation=INSERT, additionalData='null', comments='null', tenants='[TenantInfo {bu_id=2, mart_id=2}]'}, payload=null]"; line: 1, column: 2]"

Comment: I was trying like new TypeReference<List<Event>>(). Though the approach worked for String and other object types, it failed for array of objects. Thanks for your suggestion